# select a particular value from the drop down in web page using vb script

Tags: vba

i am having some values in drop down of web page.

i want to select a particular value from that drop down using VBA.

Thanks in advance,

Hitendra

Comment: What have you tried? What was the problem, what didn't work? You should also show us some code to understand what you're using in VB.NET (maybe ASP.NET?) and what's the VBA part. Currently your question doesn't make much sense and shows little effort.

Answer (score -3):

Should be:

```
ddlMyDropDownList.Items(index) //starting with 0
```

Comment: Hell, then why even bother?